# Different outcome using pandas nunique() and unique()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a big `DF` with `10 millions` rows and I need to find the unique number for each column.

I wrote the function below:
(need to return a series)

```py
def count_unique_values(df):
    return pd.Series(df.nunique())
```

and I get this output:

```py
Area          210
Item          436
Element         4
Year           53
Unit            2
Value      313640
dtype: int64
```

expected result should be value 313641.

when I just do

```py
df['Value'].unique()
```

I do get that answer. Didn't figure out why I get less with `nunique()` just there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because [`DataFrame.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) omit missing values, because default parameter `dropna=True`, [`Series.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) function not.

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
        'D':[np.nan,3,5,5,3,5],

})

print (df)
   A    D
0  a  NaN
1  b  3.0
2  c  5.0
3  d  5.0
4  e  3.0
5  f  5.0

def count_unique_values(df):
    return df.nunique()

print (count_unique_values(df))
A    6
D    2
dtype: int64

print (df['D'].unique())
[nan  3.  5.]
```

---

```
print (df['D'].nunique())
2

print (df['D'].unique())
[nan  3.  5.]
```

---

Solution is add parameter `dropna=False`:

```
print (df['D'].nunique(dropna=False))
3

print (df['D'].unique())
3
```

So in your function:

```
def count_unique_values(df):
    return df.nunique(dropna=False)
print (count_unique_values(df))
A    6
D    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: So if i'd like to count Nones I should use unique and if I don't I should use nunique?

Comment: @ShayHa - Need `dropna=False` parameter, edited answer.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much.I really appreciated the information you gave me.

Comment: Very helpful explanation. Do you @jezrael know the reasoning behind this design? It seems surprising / inconsistent to me.